# how to generate an image for each user in node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I am making a guess the number game over socket.io in node.js Lets say I ask the person to guess the a number 124 which is obviously shown to the user as 12_ ,I want to tell the person complete 12_, if they guessed 4 as the last digit, that would be right answer, how do I send an image containing the text 12_ for each person over socket.io. I need a way to generate images. I believe storing images for a large number of people would be a bad idea. or could I simply have 7 or 8 plain backgrounds and dynamically overlay text that I want on these backgrounds and send it to the user.

**What have I tried**
I cannot use node-canvas as it needs a native dependency on Heroku
I cannot use GraphicsMagick as Heroku s free plan doesnt support it
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

you have to read the image and convert into base64 on the server side

```
socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: buf.toString('base64') });
```

where as  on the client side you can use websocket to receive image

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

socket.on("image", function(info) {
  if (info.image) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + info.buffer;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how do I generate a different image for each person, i want to generate images on the fly, i can literally ask a person to guess any number from 12_ to _3_456 and i dont want to store images for all possible combination of digits and underscore characters

Comment: sorry wrong comment, how do I generate image for a non browser client, something like send a url to them and they see an image , is that even possible

Comment: study **canvas**, you can create canvas image at nodejs server end at runtime and pass emit image or you can send text from server side and make image at runtime on client end.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a really old question, but maybe it helps someone (as there's very little info about this).

I just wanted to say that **you can use GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick in Heroku**. [You just need to add a buildpack](https://github.com/mcollina/heroku-buildpack-graphicsmagick) for it to work (it works even on free instances).

Here's a blogpost I made saying how I used [GraphicsMagick in Node.js](http://gonzalogm.com/2017/01/23/dynamic-images-with-graphicsmagick-on-node-js/). You can check [the code on Github](https://github.com/GonzaloGM/carpoolear-trip-images) (fair warning, the code sucks, but hey, it works).